# How to make text branching into two columns?

Tags: paracol, branching

**Hello everyone**

How to do everything as in the picture ? (with arrows)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks , Mensch)

Comment: As `tikz` picture should be simple ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only the package `paracol`.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}% margins
    
\usepackage{paracol}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\setcolumnwidth{0.33\textwidth,5pt,0.33\textwidth,5pt,0.33\textwidth}%  column separation =5pt

\newcommand{\pointleftarrow}{{\Huge\bfseries$\swarrow$}}
\newcommand{\pointrightarrow}{{\Huge\bfseries$\searrow$}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
    
\raggedright
    
\begin{paracol}{5}  

\switchcolumn[2] % start in the center column (#2)      
 \lipsum[66]


\switchcolumn[3]*\pointrightarrow
\switchcolumn[1]\pointleftarrow
    
\switchcolumn[4]* % right column (#4) and start new paragraph
\medskip
 \lipsum[66]

\switchcolumn[0] %  lef tcolumn (#0)
\medskip    
\lipsum[66]

\switchcolumn[1]*\pointrightarrow
\switchcolumn[3]\pointleftarrow
    
\switchcolumn[2]*   % center (#2) and start new paragraph 
\medskip    
 \lipsum[66]
    
\end{paracol}   
    
\end{document}
```

It is simple to change the arrows to achieve other effects with `tikz`

[image: zz]

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\pointleftarrow}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [-Stealth, very thick] (-0.5,0)--(-0.5,-1)--(-1.3,-1);        
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewcommand{\pointrightarrow}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [-Stealth, very thick] (-0.5,0)--(-0.5,-1)--(0.3,-1);         
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Present desired solutions as `tikz` picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                matrix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
M/.style = {matrix of nodes,
            nodes={text width=0.4\linewidth, anchor=south},
            column sep=-0.1\linewidth,
            row sep=5ex},
every edge/.append style = {draw, -Straight Barb, very thick}
                        ]   
\matrix (m) [M] 
{  &   \lipsum[66]  &               \\
\lipsum[66]     &   &   \lipsum[66] \\
   &   \lipsum[66]  &               \\
}; 
\draw   (m-1-2) edge (m-2-1)    (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3)
        (m-2-1) edge (m-3-2)    (m-2-3) edge (m-3-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Next time, please provide what you tray yourself and explain where you stuck

Comment: Thank you , Zarko !

Comment: - "Next time, please provide what you tray yourself and explain where you stuck" 
- I understand .